# How can i use the specific data that save in GCP Big Query with cloud function to compare with a value when reached then send an alert to user

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, alert

I am trying to use the cloud function to take the specific data from the big query and I also want it to compare with the threshold value that I set. When the specific data reach the threshold value then it will send an email to the user.

How should I use the Cloud Function to get the data from Big Query and compare it with the threshold value? Is there any suggestion in the coding part for the cloud function

This is the code that I used to send an email when the value has reached the threshold value

```
def email(request):
import os
from sendgrid import SendGridAPIClient
from sendgrid.helpers.mail import Mail, Email
from python_http_client.exceptions import HTTPError

sg = SendGridAPIClient(os.environ['EMAIL_API_KEY'])

html_content = "<p>Hello World!</p>"

message = Mail(
    to_emails="[Destination]@email.com",
    from_email=Email('[YOUR]@gmail.com', "Your name"),
    subject="Hello world",
    html_content=html_content
    )
message.add_bcc("[YOUR]@gmail.com")

try:
    response = sg.send(message)
    return f"email.status_code={response.status_code}"
    #expected 202 Accepted

except HTTPError as e:
    return e.message
```

Comment: Why don't you query the data in BigQuery with the threshold in the where clause? Or use a parametrized query? Like that, all the result that you get are mail to send, no check to perform in Cloud Functions

Comment: The data in BigQuery were already queried, and now I want to set a threshold value to the data when one of the data has reached or below the threshold value then need to send an email to the user. For example, there are a few types of data, battery level, temperature, moisture. I need to set if the battery level is lower than 50% then send an alert(email) to the user. What should I do in BigQuery?

Comment: The bigquery filtering performance are awesome compare to your Cloud Functions. In addition, you won't pay for the processing time with BigQuery, only for the volume of data that you scan. With Cloud Function, you need to check all the rows, perform a test on values to determine if you must send an email or not. It consume CPU and Memory time to do that and it's not so efficient, and less scalable than a BigQuery query.

Comment: What if I use Big Query to do the comparison and What should I do? If I must send an email to alert the user can I keep using Big Query to do compare and alert?

Comment: You perform your query with the thresholds values in the query. All the results that you will get from BigQuery are those on which you have to send an email. No check in your Cloud Functions, simply get the result and send email. The comparison is performed in the BigQuery query

Comment: How should I set the threshold in the Query?

Comment: I don't know your query and your thresholds!! Share more details if you need help on that part (your query (or a similar/simpler) and the code that call BigQuery with your query)

Comment: SELECT milliVolt FROM `zeta-pivot` 
where milliVolt > 3400
limit 100 (THIS IS THE QUERY AND THRESHOLD)

Comment: The query and threshold I code like above and I get the data I need. How should I set to send an email to the user know?